# How to get flow lines through the decision box in this flow chart?

Tags: css, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I create a flow chart in HTML and CSS, where I use the decision box from which two decisions have to be made. One is coming below but the sideline flow which again redirects to the first box in the flow chart on answer 'no' in the decision box. So how to add a line in decision box to the first box in the flowchart?

```css
#no1 {
  width:300px;
  height:60px;
  margin:auto;
}
#no1 a {
  height:60px;
}
#line1{
  font-size:0;
  width:1px;
  height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  margin:auto;
}
.diamond {
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.diamond:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4286f4;  
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
.diamond-inner {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font: 19px Helvetica, Arial, Times;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="flow_container">
  <div id="no1"><%= button_to A, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to B, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>               
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to C, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div class='diamond'>
    <div class="diamond-inner">
      <%= Decision %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="line1"></div>            

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to D, usemap="#", :method => "get", \
   class: "flowchartButtonOval" %></div>
 </div>
```

I tried many ways to add line in HTML and CSS form but they are not aligning well.

I provide all the required code I used. Please try or just share some links of code with me, where flowcharts in HTML and CSS are created with decision box with flow lines.

[i need almost like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgqkU.png)

Comment: can put some static content instead of dynamic..

Comment: yeah, but if the screen size changes then it is moving.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of what you are expecting. thanks

Comment: yeah got one, check it. The line arrowed i need.

Comment: i have added an answer please check. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used pseudo classes to achieve it. hope it helps. thanks

```css
#no1 {
  width:300px;
  height:60px;
  margin:auto;
}
#no1 a {
  height:60px;
}
#line1{
  font-size:0;
  width:1px;
  height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  margin:auto;
}
.diamond {
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.diamond:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4286f4;  
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
.diamond-inner {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font: 19px Helvetica, Arial, Times;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

.diamond-inner:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 368px;
    width: 2px;
    top: -360px;
    background-color: black;
    left: -130px;}
    
.diamond-inner:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 87px;
    top: 6px;
    background-color: black;
    left: -130px;}
    
 .top:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 29px;
    left: -70px;}
    
 .top:before {
        content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid black;
    position: absolute;
top: 20px;
    left: -15px;
}

.top{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="flow_container">
  <div id="no1" class="top"><%= button_to A, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to B, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>               
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to C, usemap="#", :method => "get", 
   disabled: true, class: "flowchartButtonBlue" %></div>
  <div id="line1"></div>

  <div class='diamond'>
    <div class="diamond-inner">
      <%= Decision %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="line1"></div>            

  <div id="no1"><%= button_to D, usemap="#", :method => "get", \
   class: "flowchartButtonOval" %></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I need kinda, but it needs too much alignment. But thanks for clue. I will work on it.

Comment: It is not responsive, on different width it is moving to right.

Comment: Thanks, very nicely interpreted.